# How to print a class that can contain itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, recursion

I have a class that functions similarly to a list. It can contain itself and that leads to issues printing. Python handles this with replacing the recursive part with Ellipsis. I can do that when the nesting is simple where `a = []; a.append(a)` by comparing individual items with self, but when there are more complicated relationships this doesn't work. What is a good way to replace recursive parts with Ellipsis or hijack pythons printing mechanism? I tried to construct a list out of the values from self and return `str(mylist)`, but I got a Recursion error from that too.

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        #stuff happens

    def __repr__(self):
        s = []
        for i in range(self.length):
            if self[i] is self:
                s.append("[...]")
            else:
                s.append(repr(self[i]))
        return f"[{','.join(s)}]"

class bar:
    def __init__(self):
        # stuff happens

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(list(self))

a = foo()
b = foo()
a.append(b)
b.append(a)
print(a)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

a = bar()
b = bar()
a.append(b)
b.append(a)
print(a)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: Just keep track of all the objects you've seen in a set

Comment: @juanpa What if they're not hashable? use a list? put their `id` in the set instead?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/reprlib.html

Comment: your code is incomplete, there is no `append` method in `foo` and `bar`

Comment: Beside the point, but a `length` attribute is unpythonic. You should make a [`__len__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__) method. Also, `for i in range(len(self)): ... self[i]` would be better written as `for i in self: ... i`, but you'd need an [`__iter__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__) method.

Comment: @wjandrea. Not true. `__len__` and `__getitem__` are sufficient

Comment: @Mad Instead of `__iter__`? Oh, I didn't know that, thanks!

Comment: @wjandrea. Yup, and mappings are identified by a `keys` method, of all things. Relics of the old days.

Comment: @wjandrea the `length` attribute is meant for internal use. I can rename it to `_length`, but should I also be using the external interface internally where available?

Comment: @RedKnite Yeah, using `len` inside the class is clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using reprlib, recommended by snakecharmerb, I solved the issue with the decorator [`reprlib.recursive_repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/reprlib.html#reprlib.recursive_repr). The description of that function is:

> `@reprlib.recursive_repr(fillvalue="...")`
>
> Decorator for `__repr__()` methods to detect recursive calls within the same thread. If 
>   a recursive call is made, the *fillvalue* is returned, otherwise, the usual `__repr__()` 
>   call is made.

I use the fillvalue `"[...]"` with brackets because otherwise the result can end up looking like `[3, ...]` which is not pretty and not the way python formats lists.

```py
@reprlib.recursive_repr("[...]")
def __repr__(self):
    return f"[{','.join(map(repr, self))}]"
```